# How to creat a target dataframe applying multiple condition between the rows of a panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am asking below question as I don't find any suitable answer based on the `multiple  condition` apply on `different rows` of a `data-frame`.

I have below `data-frame`  where I want to apply `multiple condition` on its `rows` to create a new `data-frame`

```
    timestamp      t_id b_id    id   b_sent   lc
0   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       C_0  25      540
1   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       C_1  25      540
2   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       C_2  25      540
3   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       C_3  28      478
4   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       V_0  25      NA
5   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       V_1  25      NA
6   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       V_2  25      NA
7   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       V_3  91      NA
8   6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       C_0  26      510
9   6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       C_1  26      510
10  6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       C_2  27      510
11  6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       C_3  32      300
12  6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       V_0  26      NA
13  6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       V_1  26      NA
14  6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       V_2  26      NA
15  6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       V_3  26      NA

16  6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       C_0  10      140
17  6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       C_1  20      340
18  6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       C_2  25      240
19  6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       C_3  30      578
20  6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       V_0  25      NA
21  6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       V_1  25      NA
22  6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       V_2  25      NA
23  6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       V_3  91      NA
24  6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       C_0  15      140
25  6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       C_1  20      340
26  6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       C_2  35      240
27  6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       C_3  40      578
28  6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       V_0  25      NA
29  6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       V_1  35      NA
30  6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       V_2  45      NA
31  6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       V_3  25      NA
```

The output will be based on condition below where `timestamps` should be the same:

```
b_sent_new = b_sent(b_id==1,id=='C_0') + b_sent(b_id==2,id=='V_0')   
b_sent_new = b_sent(b_id==1,id=='C_1') + b_sent(b_id==2,id=='V_1')
b_sent_new = b_sent(b_id==1,id=='C_2') + b_sent(b_id==2,id=='V_2')
b_sent_new = b_sent(b_id==1,id=='C_3') + b_sent(b_id==2,id=='V_3')
and vice verca
b_sent_new = b_sent(b_id==2,id=='C_0') + b_sent(b_id==1,id=='V_0')   
b_sent_new = b_sent(b_id==2,id=='C_1') + b_sent(b_id==1,id=='V_1')
b_sent_new = b_sent(b_id==2,id=='C_2') + b_sent(b_id==1,id=='V_2')
b_sent_new = b_sent(b_id==2,id=='C_3') + b_sent(b_id==1,id=='V_3')
```

for example, `b_sent_new` value will be the `b_sent` value where `b_id=1` and `id=C_0` plus the `b_sent` value where `b_id=2` and `id=V_0` of within the same `timestamp'

More precisely, for `b_id` value 1, `b_sent_new` value of corresponding `C_0` will be `b_sent` values of `C_0` of `b_id` `1` plus the `b_sent` value of `V_0` of `b_id` `2`

desired output:

```
    timestamp         t_id  b_id    id   b_sent   lc    b_sent_new
    0   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       C_0  25      540    51  
    1   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       C_1  26      540    53 
    2   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       C_2  22      540    50  
    3   6/1/2020 9:00   25  1       C_3  28      478    47   
    4   6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       C_0  30      510    48  
    5   6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       C_1  31      510    47  
    6   6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       C_2  32      510    49  
    7   6/1/2020 9:00   25  2       C_3  33      300    51
    8   6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       C_0  10      140    35
    9   6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       C_1  20      340    55
   10   6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       C_2  25      240    70
   11   6/1/2020 9:30   25  1       C_3  30      578    55
   12   6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       C_0  15      140    40
   13   6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       C_1  20      340    45
   14   6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       C_2  35      240    60
   15   6/1/2020 9:30   25  2       C_3  40      578    131
```

The approach I am currently following is not giving me the appropriate output:

```
box_1 = df[df.b_id.isin(["1"])].reset_index(drop = True)
box_2 = df[df.b_id.isin(["2"])].reset_index(drop = True)

box_1['new'] = np.where((box_1['timestamp'] == box_2['timestamp'] ) & (box_1['id']=="C_0") & (box_2['id'].shift(-4)=="V_0"), box_1['b_sent']+box_2['b_sent'].shift(-4), np.nan)
box_1['new'] = np.where((box_1['timestamp'] == box_2['timestamp'] ) & (box_1['id']=="C_1") & (box_2['id'].shift(-4)=="V_1"), box_1['b_sent']+box_2['b_sent'].shift(-4), np.nan)
box_1['new'] = np.where((box_1['timestamp'] == box_2['timestamp'] ) & (box_1['id']=="C_2") & (box_2['id'].shift(-4)=="V_2"), box_1['b_sent']+box_2['b_sent'].shift(-4), np.nan)
box_1['new'] = np.where((box_1['timestamp'] == box_2['timestamp'] ) & (box_1['id']=="C_3") & (box_2['id'].shift(-4)=="V_3"), box_1['b_sent']+box_2['b_sent'].shift(-4), np.nan)
```

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: kindly explain the logic a bit more, and add the final dataframe as it should be, without the comments

Comment: @sammywemmy explained the logic and edited the output,hope this will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be friendlier way to do this, but this should get you started. It creates a much wider dataframe that you'll have to modify to meet your needs (deleting columns and renaming headers). I left it for transparency so you see what's happening.

Essentially, I'm pulling apart your dataframe using groupby on the dates id, and piecing it all back together at the end.

Also, based on your inputs, I don't think your expected output calculations for b_sent_new are all correct. If I'm wrong here, let me know.

```
dflist = []
def calc_new(x):
    # print(x[(x['b_id']==1) & (x['id'].str.contains('C_'))].sort_values(['timestamp', 'b_id'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True))
    # print(x[(x['b_id']==2) & (x['id'].str.contains('V_'))].sort_values(['timestamp', 'b_id'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True))
    # print(x[(x['b_id']==1) & (x['id'].str.contains('V_'))].sort_values(['timestamp', 'b_id'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True))
    # print(x[(x['b_id']==2) & (x['id'].str.contains('C_'))].sort_values(['timestamp', 'b_id'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True))

    a = x[(x['b_id']==1) & (x['id'].str.contains('C_'))].sort_values(['timestamp', 'b_id'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
    b = x[(x['b_id']==2) & (x['id'].str.contains('V_'))].sort_values(['timestamp', 'b_id'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
    c = x[(x['b_id']==1) & (x['id'].str.contains('V_'))].sort_values(['timestamp', 'b_id'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
    d = x[(x['b_id']==2) & (x['id'].str.contains('C_'))].sort_values(['timestamp', 'b_id'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    e = a.merge(b, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    e['b_sent_new'] = e['b_sent_x'] + e['b_sent_y']
    # print(e)
    f = d.merge(c, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    f['b_sent_new'] = f['b_sent_x'] + f['b_sent_y']
    # print(f)
    dflist.append(e)
    dflist.append(f)
    return None
    
dft = df.groupby('timestamp').apply(calc_new)
# dflist
final_df = pd.concat(dflist)
final_df

     timestamp_x  t_id_x  b_id_x id_x  b_sent_x   lc_x    timestamp_y  t_id_y  b_id_y id_y  b_sent_y  lc_y  b_sent_new
0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       1  C_0        25  540.0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       2  V_0        26   NaN          51
1  6/1/2020 9:00      25       1  C_1        25  540.0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       2  V_1        26   NaN          51
2  6/1/2020 9:00      25       1  C_2        25  540.0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       2  V_2        26   NaN          51
3  6/1/2020 9:00      25       1  C_3        28  478.0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       2  V_3        26   NaN          54
0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       2  C_0        26  510.0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       1  V_0        25   NaN          51
1  6/1/2020 9:00      25       2  C_1        26  510.0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       1  V_1        25   NaN          51
2  6/1/2020 9:00      25       2  C_2        27  510.0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       1  V_2        25   NaN          52
3  6/1/2020 9:00      25       2  C_3        32  300.0  6/1/2020 9:00      25       1  V_3        91   NaN         123
0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       1  C_0        10  140.0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       2  V_0        25   NaN          35
1  6/1/2020 9:30      25       1  C_1        20  340.0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       2  V_1        35   NaN          55
2  6/1/2020 9:30      25       1  C_2        25  240.0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       2  V_2        45   NaN          70
3  6/1/2020 9:30      25       1  C_3        30  578.0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       2  V_3        25   NaN          55
0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       2  C_0        15  140.0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       1  V_0        25   NaN          40
1  6/1/2020 9:30      25       2  C_1        20  340.0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       1  V_1        25   NaN          45
2  6/1/2020 9:30      25       2  C_2        35  240.0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       1  V_2        25   NaN          60
3  6/1/2020 9:30      25       2  C_3        40  578.0  6/1/2020 9:30      25       1  V_3        91   NaN         131
```

Comment: Merci! @Jonathan Leon for this code! its work perfectly for me.Though it takes little bit  time but its negligible due to the size of my huge data set.

Comment: Thanks! Glad it worked. I couldn't get my head around vectorizing it, so apply() it is.